# How to detect individuals who have at least one misordered number

Tags: r

Here is a representation of my dataset:

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,
      2,2,2,
      3,3,
      4,4,4,4)

order<-c(44,44,45,41,
        13,21,2013,
        21,10,
        45,65,74,877)

mydata<-data.frame(
  ID=ID,order=order
)


  ID Time order
1   1    1    44
2   1    2    44
3   1    3    45
4   1    4    41
5   2    1    13
6   2    2    21
7   2    3  2013
8   3    1    21
9   3    2    10
10  4    1    45
11  4    2    65
12  4    3    74
13  4    4   877
```

The variable `order` should increase with time.
With a program, I should detect all the individuals (ID=1 and ID=3 in this case) that have variable `order` that decreases  at a time of follow-up.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.unsorted.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 unique(subset(mydata, ave(order, ID, FUN=\(x)c(0, diff(x)))<0)$ID)
[1] 1 3
```

or if you want the rows back:

```
subset(mydata, ave(order, ID, FUN=\(x)c(0, diff(x)))<0)
  ID order
4  1    41
9  3    10

library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0

mydata %>% 
   filter(order<lag(order), .by=ID)

  ID order
1  1    41
2  3    10
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Roland's comment, check `is.unsorted`:

```r
unique(mydata$ID[with(mydata, ave(order, ID, FUN = is.unsorted)) == 1])
#[1] 1 3
```

or

```r
subset(mydata, ave(order, ID, FUN = is.unsorted) == 1)
#  ID order
#1  1    44
#2  1    44
#3  1    45
#4  1    41
#8  3    21
#9  3    10
```

---

In `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0
filter(mydata, is.unsorted(order), .by = ID)
```

In `data.table`:

```r
setDT(mydata)[, .SD[is.unsorted(order)], by = ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could check if the `rank(order)` corresponds to the `row_number()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  filter(row_number() != rank(order, ties.method = "first"), .by = ID)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID order
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    44
#> 2     1    44
#> 3     1    45
#> 4     1    41
#> 5     3    21
#> 6     3    10
```

To just get the `ID` of the individuals we can add `pull(ID) %>% unique()` to the pipe:

```
mydata %>% 
  filter(row_number() != rank(order, ties.method = "first"), .by = ID) %>% 
  pull(ID) %>% 
  unique()
#> 1 3
```

Data from OP

```r
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,
      2,2,2,
      3,3,
      4,4,4,4)

order<-c(44,44,45,41,
         13,21,2013,
         21,10,
         45,65,74,877)

mydata<-data.frame(
  ID=ID,order=order
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>